# how to send and retrieve message through android to PC(How PC and Android device Communicate using USB)

Tags: android, communication

I have an Android device and I connected it to the computer through USB. I need to send message and retrieve message through this device to my PC. Can I do this without using Bluetooth and wifi?

Comment: Which device is to serve as the master here?  Do you want to have PC control the message flow or the android device?  If you want PC to be the master, then ADB is the way to go; if android - then (simply put) this cannot be done.

Comment: if android is a master then wht should I do

Comment: @Tirashi As I said, you cannot do it if android is the master. The PC will not allow this: whether you use windows, mac or linux, the OS will always treat any connected device as a slave in the communication.  You might be able to write some low-level drivers to be sitting on the phone to allow the PC to be seen as something other than a USB host, but I doubt you'd be able to actually do it properly. Again, the simple answer to your question is "you cannot do it".

Comment: ok..so can i send message through the PC which will show on Android device

Comment: Thanks Aleks G..I am really thankful to you for helping me.

Comment: Yes, once you're connected over USB, you can use adb to pass messages to the device.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing the ADB drivers provided with the Android SDK ? ADB serves for debugging so it should help you.

Comment: thanks but How can I pass message is there any application for it,or some example

Comment: what are you trying to pass ? What sort of message ? The description is a bit vague. You mean a SMS ? A message via code/console ?